# package android.support.v7.internal.view.menu does not exist: cannot find symbol class MenuBuilder

Tags: android, android-support-library

I just upgraded my support library from `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` from `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`.

It gave me this error:

> package android.support.v7.internal.view.menu does not exist: cannot
>   find symbol class MenuBuilder

I use popupmenu's in my app.

According to google, PopUpMenu inherits interface com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.Callback and hence I got a list of errors when I gradle build my app: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

Does anyone know whether this interface is deprecated?

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I had to roll back to 23.1.0, not sure what new capabilities they added in 23.1.1 but 23.1.0 was enough for me at least until google fix this.

Comment: Ok, so we have to wait... I hate those things :(

Comment: try replacing it with `android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView`... seems like the path changed...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

They changed the package slightly, removing the 'internal'.  You just need to change your imports:

`android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder`

to

`android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder`

Comment: And when you have a huge project, you need to change it everywhere. Thanks. No, really.. thanks Android.. It's ok to break everything.

Comment: This change has blown up my project!

Comment: Can't wait for the day I can work with Xamarin for a couple hours straight without encountering a bug of some sort.

Comment: Needed to change it once (bottom-sheet-lib).

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the solution and the Build it again. You might have problems with the versions of packages or dlls in your solution.