# ContextThemeWrapper not working

Tags: android, gradle

> Error:(11, 40) error: package android.support.v7.internal.view does not exist
>   Error:(30, 25) error: cannot find symbol class ContextThemeWrapper

I get that error even though in my gradle I have this included. What is the solution? not a strange error? I cannot run my app because of this error and its annoying. I have no jar in my libs folder as well.

```
dependencies { 
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
         compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a change in `appcompat-v7:23.1.1`, some elements inside package `android.support.v7.internal.view` were moved to `android.support.v7.view`. Changing your imports may solve the problem.

For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33739331/4848308) answer

Or simply rollback `appcompat-v7` to `23.0.1` in your `build.gradle`

Hope it helps!!